# Error 500 during uploading a backup file into Drupal on pc

Tags: drupal, backup

I am beginner in Drupal, I have downloaded site file from the dev server using Git and while I am trying to run these files in the htdocs(xampp) by localhost. I got the below error

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost 05/30/12 14:30:17 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21
>   OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Answer (score 0):

The following link has more details but basicly you need to firs backup and download the database used on yor dev drupal site and upload it on your copy of xampp. After that you need to edit your configuration and maybe your .htacess (if not using the default one that comes with drupal) for your local pc.

http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/95

http://drupal.org/node/350271